# Null pointer querying embedded objects in array

Tags: arrays, nullpointerexception, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to do something trivial without success. 
I have the **Profile** pojo entity which contain an array of **Items**, each items contain **itemId** field and few more fields which are not relevant to the use-case 
I am using spring-data-mongo version 1.1.0.M1.

I am trying to retrieve all the profiles which has items in a given set of ids...

mongoTemplate.find(
                    Query.query(Criteria.where("items.itemId").in(
                            objectIds)), Profile.class);

I am getting **NullPointerExcpetion** for the above query, what am I doing wrong?